# on demand email to case in salesforce creating duplicate case when user replies

Tags: apex, trigger, service-cloud-console, email2case

When the user replies to mail then it's creating a new case.

- In auto response added a subject and case thread id but mail is not appending as a replay(as New mail).
- In EmailMessageTrigger querying cases with matching subject and email address. then we are assigning matched caseid to parentId. here email is added to old case but its creating new Case.

Comment: You need to re-verify case thread id, if case thread id would be different then it will create new case. Also verify when user reply to email that case thread id should be mentioned in the email.

Comment: if user replays to that mail before attaching the thread id. then it's creating a duplicate case.

Comment: yes, that's correct if user replying without case thread id it will create duplicate case.

Comment: any workaround to avoid creating a duplicate case.
i have gone through this link( http://sforcehacks.blogspot.com/2012/01/email-to-case-can-create-too-many-cases.html)
 but it's working on inbound email handler.

Comment: May be you can add case thread id in these places, template, subject and body of email.